# Easily map over Hash like Array#map

Tags: ruby, hash

Sometimes I want to map over a collection.
If it's an array it's easy:

```
foo = [1,2,3]
foo.map {|v| v + 1}
#=> [2, 3, 4]
```

But a hash doesn't work the same way:

```
bar = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
bar.map{|k,v| v+1}
#=> [2, 3, 4]
```

What I'd really like is something like:

```
bar = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
bar.baz{|k,v| v+1}
#=> {:a=>2, :b=>3, :c=>4}
```

where `Hash#baz` is some method. Is there an easy way to get a "map-like" experience for a hash?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Ruby 2.4 you can use the built-in [`Hash#transform_values`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values):

```
bar = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
# => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
bar.transform_values {|v| v+1 }
# => {:a=>2, :b=>3, :c=>4}
```

Comment: nice... is there a `transform_keys`?

Comment: @sagarpandya82 Nope. [It was discussed along with `transform_values`](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12512) but  for some reason I can't discern it was dropped.

Comment: @Jordan. Possibly because `transform_values` merely overwrites `values` while `transform_keys` would need to remove old key-value pairs and create new ones with a different key but the same value. It wouldn't be much different than creating a new hash with `map{...}.to_h`. It might have been useful nonetheless.

Comment: ...or `bar.transform_values(&:next)`.

Comment: Yes, those will both work, but I suspect that incrementing the values in the hash is not the actual problem with which OP is tasked.

Comment: @SagarPandya `transform_keys` was introduced in Ruby 2.5.

Answer (score 6):

Just to point out the obvious and most common solution to address this need:

```
bar = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
# => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
bar.map { |k, v| [k, v + 1] }.to_h
# => {:a=>2, :b=>3, :c=>4}
```

Comment: `Hash[bar.map {|k,v| [k,v+1]}]` being another option.

Answer (score 4):

From the [ruby-forum](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/185611#811410), you can use [Hash#merge](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) to merge the hash with itself:

```
bar = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
#=> {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
bar.merge(bar){|k,v| v+1}
#=> {:a=>2, :b=>3, :c=>4}
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the great things about Ruby is if you don't like what's in the Ruby core you can always go and extend it to fill in the missing pieces:

```
class Hash
  def map_values
    map do |k,v|
      [ k, yield(k, v) ]
    end.to_h
  end
end
```

Which gives you the thing you wanted:

```
bar = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
# => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
bar.map_values{ |k,v| v+1 }
# => {:a=>2, :b=>3, :c=>4}
```

I'm surprised this hasn't been introduced into core Ruby, but it might be in the future.

**Update**: As Eric points out, [`transform_values`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) is now in Ruby 2.4.0. This is also in ActiveSupport if you're using Rails 4.2 or later.

```
bar = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
# => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
bar.transform_values{ |v| v+1 }
# => {:a=>2, :b=>3, :c=>4}
```

Comment: Welcome to the [future](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values)! ;)

Comment: @EricDuminil Oh, nice! I went looking for something like that but didn't think it'd end up under *T* in the list. Yeah, I'd recommend using that.

Comment: Note that the block only accepts the value as argument.

Comment: Note that Active Support's core extensions makes it easy to pull only that functionality into non-Rails scripts. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#working-with-values

Answer (score 1):

```
bar = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}

bar.merge(bar) { |*,v| v+1 }
  #=> {:a=>2, :b=>3, :c=>4}
```

This uses the form of [Hash.merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that employs a block to return the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged, which here is all keys.

Another way:

```
bar.keys.each { |k| bar[k] += 1 }
bar
  #=> {:a=>2, :b=>3, :c=>4}
```

which can be written in one line using [Object#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-tap):

```
bar.tap { |h| h.keys.each { |k| h[k] += 1 } }
  #=> {:a=>2, :b=>3, :c=>4}
```

Comment: It's probably better to use `_` than `*` as the *don't care* argument name.

Comment: What are the naming rules for the _don't care_ argument?

Comment: @tadman, please elaborate. I could use `|_,_,v|`, `|_*,v|` or `|*,v|`. Why is one preferred over the others?

Comment: `*` is a sponge, `_` ignores a specific thing. If you're dealing with a *bunch* of arguments you don't care about, `*` is the way to go, but using it freely might confuse methods that test the *arity* of your block. It's a bad habit to get into. `*,x` and `_,_,x` look very different when reflected on, one has 0..1 arguments, the other exactly 3.